# Parent constructor call overridden functions before all child constructors are finished

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

ECMAScript 6 (Harmony) introduces `classes` with ability to inherit one from another. Suppose I have a game and some basic class to describe basic things for bot behavior. I simplify my real architecture but suppose I need to run `render` and some another routine and I put this calls in basic `Bot` class.

```
class Bot{
  constructor(){
    render();
  }
  render(){}
}
```

Each bot then override it's `render` function and can have some settings in constructor:

```
class DevilBot extends Bot{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.color = 0xB4D333;
  }
  render(){
    createSomeMesh(this.color);
  }
}
```

The problem here is that before I call `super()` - `this` does not exist. But `super` (parent constructor) will call the overridden `render` that would need the `color` variable defined in the child constructor. I can suppose in the parent constructor that the child object would implement some `init` function with all needed settings and call it:

```
class Bot{
  constructor(){
    if (this.init) this.init();
    render();
  }
  render(){}
}

class DevilBot extends Bot{
  init(){
    this.color = 0xB4D333;
  }
  render(){
    createSomeMesh(this.color);
  }
}
```

But how good this approach and what is a preferred way to solve such a problem?

Comment: The only solution is don't call overridable method in constructor. doing it in C# will give you a [warning](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx).

Comment: This is one reason why objects of some types often have a constructor and a separate `.init()` method because the `.init()` method runs after the object is fully formed and all overrides are in place.

Comment: The solution could be as simple as not automatically calling other functions  (such as `render`) that depend on instance properties. What's the harm in calling `this.render()` manually after invoking your `Bot` subclasses? PS, to call a member function within your class, you will need `this.render()` instead of `render()`.

Comment: @naomik, the reason I call it in constructor is that in my real architecture I have more complex code routine that I don't want to be repeated in each child object.

Comment: This looks like bad design. The purpose of a constructor is to construct and initialise objects, not to `render` them (a side effect)

Comment: @Bergi, this looks like bad design only because I use `render` in this example for simplification. As I write in previous comment, in real architecture I have more complex code that I want to hide in parent object.

Comment: Can't you just declare a method with the complex code that you call from the children?

Comment: I wonder what your "render" function would do on a Bot instance. If you need a color to render an object, then put the color attribute where it belongs, i.e. in your Bot class.

Comment: @kuroineko, as I explained 2 times in previous comments - `render` and `color` are just for sake of simplicity, just to demonstrate problem.

Comment: No matter if it's a color or anything else. You're putting an attribute in a subclass and expect the parent to use it. Sounds like a wrong design choice to me.

Answer (score 5):

The following code will do what you want, though it is currently only supported in FF 41+ and Chrome 47+ (see https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)

```
class Bot{
    constructor(){
        if (new.target === Bot)
            this.render();
    }
    render(){
        console.log('Bot rendered');
    }
}

class DevilBot extends Bot{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.color = 0xB4D333;
        this.render();
    }
    render(){
        console.log('DevilBot rendered with', this.color);
    }
}

var bot = new Bot();       // Bot rendered
var dev = new DevilBot();  // DevilBot rendered with 11850547
```