# How to use ES6 super to call parent method in child constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, super, es6-class

### Situation:

I'm extending Node.js (v. 8.4.0) Error object with additional properties (timestamp, id) and then extending this object to get more granular error handling.

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.id = uuid();
    this.timestamp = Date.now();
    // I reckon this can be replaced by this.init(this) ?
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    Error.captureStackTrace && Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }

  init (self) {
    self.name = self.constructor.name;
    Error.captureStackTrace && Error.captureStackTrace(self, self.constructor);
  }
}
```

I wish to be able to not repeat the `Error.captureStackTrace` and `this.name` calls in the child errors. So I created an init function that I use in the child as such:

```
class GranularError extends MyError {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.type = "error";
    this.status = 500;
    this.code = "internalServerError";
    super.init(this);
  }
}
```

`GranularError` will then be extended again to get `MoreGranularError` etc. That's why I'd like to keep it DRY.

### Problem:

When either the GranularError or MoreGranularError is thrown, it fails with a

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).init is not a function
```

I've read mainly the following sources, but I haven't been able to apply them to the problem. Any help is appreciated.

[Call parent function which is being overridden by child during constructor chain in JavaScript(ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615034/call-parent-function-which-is-being-overridden-by-child-during-constructor-chain)

[Parent constructor call overridden functions before all child constructors are finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449880/parent-constructor-call-overridden-functions-before-all-child-constructors-are-f)

http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#referring_to_super-properties_in_methods

Comment: Your code appears to work smoothly in Chrome (https://jsfiddle.net/Lrfxum4a/). What environment are you using? (My guess is Node, based on `uuid`? What version?)

Comment: Yes, it's Node 8.4.0. I've added it to the beginning. Thanks for the comment.

It is certainly weird that it seems to run fine on Chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you are getting this error, but there is no need to create an `init` function. The `this.name` and `Error.captureStack` stuff will just work in the child as well because `this` refers to the child instance.

In other words, you are trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.id = Math.random();
    this.timestamp = Date.now();
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    Error.captureStackTrace && Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}
class GranularError extends MyError {
  constructor (msg) {
    super(msg);
    this.type = "error";
    this.status = 500;
    this.code = "internalServerError";
  }
}

console.dir(new GranularError("this is the error message"));
```

Comment: This is how the code looked before I tried to implement the init function. I must have had an error somewhere else and in trying to implement init(), I must've fixed it. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Or even better, replace `this.constructor` with `new.target`.

Comment: @Bergi Is there an actual benefit to using new.target in the above context or is it just the coolest new kid on the block?

Comment: @OndraUrban Both I guess :-) It works even before the `super()` call (as it doesn't use `this`), and nobody can mess with `.constructor` properties (although this is admittedly less of an issue with `class` syntax than it was before).